# Fullcalendar: Adding event to calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

My default calendar view is `agendaWeek`; I want the user to be able to click into an empty area on the calendar and have it automatically add a new event.  I'd like the event to already have a name and be two hours long.. so basically nothing for the user to add other than to click where they want it, then maybe move it around if they want.

I've already implemented moving existing events around and having them save (via `eventClick`).  That works nicely.  But when I tie into `dayClick` it's not working right.  Here's what I have for code:

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

  var data = {},
      url = "{method call removed}";

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', { id: 0, instructorid: 0, title: 'Class', start: date, end: date.fromNow(2), allDay: false }, true );

  {ajax-related stuff that saves the new event will go here}
```

What seems to be happening is when I click, it now creates two events... the one specified above, and then another one next to it in the same timeslot, and asks me for a name for it.

So I guess the main question is, how can I disable what appears to be the default part that trying to ask for an event name and create it?

Comment: Suggest you create a demo that replicates this. Doesn't sound like normal behavior

Comment: Okay, here's a demo:  http://www.robgapps.com/  this is a domain I don't use for anything, so I set this up as the default page.  It's a 100% static page; no back-end processing at all.